# Python GET Request with set-cookies

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to get some data from a webpage using python requests which needs to be logged in first.The login http request "response header" contains "set-cookie" parameters which is used for the next http request of the webpage. Could any tell me how to use the set-cookie for the consecutive GET request of the webpage

Comment: If you are using requests module, 

r = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
session = requests.Session()
response = session.get('http://google.com')
print(session.cookies.get_dict())
```

Or without using sessions use

```
response = requests.get('http://google.com')
response.cookies
```